# Haskell issues with split package

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I try this haskell program:

```
import Data.List.Split
main = do
    print (splitOn "," "my,list,with,commas")
```

I get this error while compiling:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lcursesw
```

This is strange because I can import and use this code in ghci, but not in an actual project.
I tried "cabal install ncurses" and "ncursesw", to no avail.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Google is suggesting cursesw is native library, you can't install it through Cabal.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on void linux and I just needed ncurses-devel.